# Admin panel not loading after upgrade to 6.5

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm upgrading Shopware from 6.4.20.2 to 6.5.5.2.
Admin panel loads, but after logging in I see a call to `api/_info/entity-schema.json` which gives a 404 response.
I have some plugins... How can I find the source of this problem?

**UPDATE 1**
It's a real 404, log

```
127.0.0.1:43802 [404]: GET /api/_info/entity-schema.json - No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE 2**
The relevant step during build-administration.sh is

```
> administration@1.0.0 convert-entity-schema
> ts-node --transpileOnly ./scripts/entitySchemaConverter/convert-schema.ts
```

here I don't see errors, except for a strange message after injecting plugins

```
WebpackDynamicPublicPath: publicPath replaced.
```

could this be the reason?

**UPDATE 3**

I tried to set a breakpoint in the `api.info.entity-schema` route, it's not stopping there (debug is ok, breakpoint on `InfoController.__construct` is hitting).

Seems to me that the route is not registered, but have no clue on the reason

**UPDATE 4**

**The problem is related to the route itself, all routes with pattern xxx. are not responding.**

Executing:

```
bin/console debug:router  | grep /api/_info/entity-schema.json
```

I get

```
api.info.entity-schema   GET           ANY      ANY    /api/_info/entity-schema.json
```

everything seems ok, but for some reason Symfony router does not process this kind of routes.
Any suggestion?

Comment: is it really a 404 or a 401 ? For a start, check your logs, this URL should be accessible.

Comment: It's a 404, from the log I see 127.0.0.1:43802 [404]: GET /api/_info/entity-schema.json - No such file or directory

Comment: If you are facing a problem with Shopware, without having written any specific code around this problem, please open a ticket in their bug tracker

Comment: I updated from 6.4.19 to 6.5.4 without any issues. Did you run the migrations with bin/console database:migrate?